# Inflate + Vertical Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm generating my layout using LayoutInflater. Basically I have a button that when is pressed the activity stops and another one starts, in the new activity the user fill some fields and the result is sent back to the last activity, so I generate a TableRow with these informations. The problem is, when I press ctrl + f11(vertical screen), the activity is destroyed and recreated, so what can I do to retrieve the informations about the inflated views?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` parameter to your activity in your manifest file, your activity will not be destroyed/recreated when orientation changes

Answer (score 0):

Persist and restore your active form data in `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: I know that, but the question is :how? I don't know if this is a good way, but what if I create a List and save it in the onSaveInstanceState? Would it be a good way? and then use a iterator and inflate everythinh again?